# How to select next and previous rows altogether from an ordered set of rows?

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am slicing the top 3 orders based on the amount like this:

```
Order::orderByDesc('amount')->take(3)->get();
```

But now, I have to go a bit further. The `orders` table has a `created_by` column which is associated with the `creator` (belongsTo) relationship. First I have to rank the orders based on the amount, and then I have to take a slice of 5 orders, where a given `created_by` value lies in the middle (the 3rd among the slice of 5 records). To translate this into a business logic:

> Show the position of a particular user on the leaderboard along with two other members who are ahead of them and two others who are behind them.

Considering Carol whose data we want to fetch, a visual representation might look like this:

- 1| Name: Alice | Order Amount: $500
- 2| Name: Bob | Order Amount: $400
- 3| Name: Carol | Order Amount: $300 // The logged-in user
- 4| Name: Diana | Order Amount: $200
- 5| Name: Emma | Order Amount: $100

One way I can think of achieving is fetching all the sorted orders into a collection and then finding the next and previous 2 rows, but for a large dataset, it would consume a lot of memory. How do I achieve this in an eloquent/database-centric way, rather than fetching all of them and then applying collection operations?

Comment: You can make 3 queries.. One to get logged in user data, one for prev users and one for next users. Second and third queries based on logged in user amount

Comment: For higher user: Order::orderByAsc('amount')->where('amount', '>', '$user->amount') - >take(2)->get()....... To get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I know SQL and it is easy to do that with Window Functions.
If you know position of the record in the "leader board", for example 3

```
SELECT
    o.name,
    o.amount
FROM (
    SELECT
        o.created_by,
        o.amount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.amount DESC) AS rn
    FROM Order o
) s
JOIN Creator c on c.id = s.created_by
WHERE
    s.rn BETWEEN 3 - 2 AND 3 + 2
```

If you know only Name of the creator:

```
WITH Ranked (name, amount, rn)
AS (
    SELECT
        o.name,
        o.amount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.amount DESC) AS rn
    FROM Order o   
    JOIN Creator c on c.id = o.created_by
)
SELECT 
    o.name,
    o.amount
FROM Ranked r
JOIN Ranked o ON o.rn BETWEEN r.rn - 2 AND r.rn + 2
WHERE r.name = `Carol`
```

It is not laravel queries, but you should know how to execute raw SQL and it can give you right direction how to write effective query.

Comment: In both queries, you are fetching all the orders. Wouldn't this be a performance issue?